# Better routing for nodejs express

Tags: node.js, routes, express

I am new to express, and got a page up and running with...

```
/*
 * Module dependencies
 */
var express = require('express'),
  stylus = require('stylus'),
  nib = require('nib'),
  app = express(),
  fs = require('fs'),
  path = require('path')

function compile(str, path) {
  return stylus(str).set('filename', path).use(nib())
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(express.logger('dev'))
app.use(stylus.middleware({
  src: __dirname + '/public',
  compile: compile
}))

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Home'
  })
})

app.use(function(req, res, next){

  // test if te file exists
  if(typeof fs.existsSync != "undefined"){
    exists = fs.existsSync
  } else {
    exists = path.existsSync
  }

  // if it does, then render it
  if(exists("views"+req.url+".jade")){
    res.render(req.url.replace(/^\//,''), { title: 'Home' })

  // otherwise render the error page
  } else {
    console.log("views"+req.url+".jade")
    res.render('404', { status: 404, url: req.url, title: '404 - what happened..?' });
  }

});

app.listen(3000)
```

The problem I am having, is that I have used a very poor check of the filesystem to determine if a page exists or not. I assume there is a much better way to handle this, but my googling has not yielded any results.

If I try to use `app.error` it gives me an `undefined` message.

I really just want to try to render any address given, and then catch errors, without the filesystem reading step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could install an error handler which will catch errors:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // ... handle error, or not ...
  next(); // see below
});
```

Ideally, you should place this as close to `app.listen()` as possible, to make it one of the last middlewares in the chain. When you do, your 'generic' handler can look like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.render(req.url.replace(/^\//,''), { title: 'Home' });
});
```

If you call `next()` in the error handler (instead of somehow generating an error page), the failed request will eventually result in a 404 (Not Found) error. Depending on your situation, this might or might not be okay. Also, *all* errors will get caught, not just missing template files.